# How to get Command line arguments for xterm in C?

Tags: c, unix, exec, xterm

My code is as follows to open a xterm terminal and run the ./paramax executable

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
execl("/usr/bin/xterm", "/usr/bin/xterm", "-hold", "./paramax", (void*)NULL);
return 0;
}
```

Now the problem is for ./paramax I need to give a commandline argument for it to execute. How to proceed with this?

Comment: Note that the last argument to `execl()` should be `(char *)NULL` rather than `(void *)NULL` since the arguments are all `char *`.  However, it is incredibly unlikely that a program would fail for this mis-cast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `xterm -e ./paramax arg and more args`, either directly or through an exec call.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to stop using `execl()` and start using `execv()` instead:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char *base_args[] = { "/usr/bin/xterm", "-hold", "./paramax", };
    enum { NUM_BASEARGS = sizeof(base_args) / sizeof(base_args[0]) };
    char *args[NUM_BASEARGS + argc];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_BASEARGS; i++)
        args[i] = base_args[i];
    for (int j = 1; j < argc; j++)
        args[i++] = argv[j];
    args[i] = 0;
    execv(args[0], args);
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to execute %s (%d: %s)\n",
            argv[0], args[0], errno, strerror(errno));
    return 1;
}
```

This allocates enough pointers in the `args` VLA (variable-length array) for the base arguments (the basic `xterm` command and arguments), plus each of the command line arguments to this program (except the program name), plus one for the final null.  It then copies the various lists of arguments into the `args`, then runs the program, reporting the error if it fails to execute the command and exiting with a failure (non-success) status.  There is no point in testing the return value from `execv()`; if it returned, it failed, and if it succeeds, it doesn't return.

Note that I am assuming that your basic `execl()` command executes the `xterm` successfully and that the `xterm` successfully runs the `./paramax` program with no extra arguments.  If that isn't working, you'll need to futz with the `base_args` list of options until it is working. However, when I tested it on Linux (Ubuntu 14.04) with a shell script `paramax` that contained just `echo Hello World`, I got an `xterm` up with `Hello World` displayed in it.  Control didn't return to the command line where I ran it until the `xterm` (which replaced the original program) exited.  You can fix that with a `fork()` before the `execv()` code, as long as you do the `execv()` in the child and exit from the parent.